# ACRA Custom Sender Pending Reports

Tags: android, acra

I'm designing a Custom sender for Acra (https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#implementing-your-own-sender) and I'm trying to determine how ACRA behaves when there is no network available. As I understand from this Issue (https://code.google.com/p/acra/issues/detail?id=11) ACRA will store a pending report if there is no internet connection and will send it out the next time ACRA.init() is called (presumably the next application start). My question is will this work with my custom sender?

```
ACRA.init(this);
ACRA.getErrorReporter().setReportSender(new MyCustomSender());
```

This is the general code structure described for use in the ACRA guide, but in looking through the code and the description in Issue 11, I believe this will not utilize my Custom sender, since it is set only after ACRA.init() is called, right? Is there another mechanism I'm missing that handles this properly so that pending reports will be sent only using my Custom Sender and not the default senders?

Answer (score 1):

I do realize I'm somewhat late with this answer. However, this is where I ended up with a bit of searching.

You can send pending reports using custom sender with this initialization:

```
private void initACRA () {
    final ReportsCrashes rc = this.getClass()
            .getAnnotation(ReportsCrashes.class);
    if (rc == null) {
        return;
    }
    ACRA.init(this, new ACRAConfiguration(rc), false);
    ErrorReporter reporter = ACRA.getErrorReporter();
    reporter.setReportSender(new MyCustomSender());
    reporter.checkReportsOnApplicationStart();
}
```

Just make sure to throw a `ReportSenderException` in the custom sender if there is no network connection/sending fails. If the report is not sent and the report file (`*-approved.stacktrace`) still disappears, make sure you catch any `RuntimeException`s and throw `ReportSenderException` instead. Both `RuntimeException` and `ReportSenderException` result in same log output from ACRA which is not the most convenient solution.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like you are correct.

It would be worthwhile revisiting ACRA config now that GoogleDocs is no longer a valid target. Something that is more amenable to injection of CustomSenders.

It should be too hard to modify ACRA to do what you want. Probably a small change to ErrorReport#setDefaultReportSenders. I'm sure a pull request would be gratefully accepted.